# How to define location of app.py in OpenShift Next Gen Developer Preview?

Tags: openshift, openshift-nextgen

It seems that a `Python 2.7` application in OpenShift requires an `app.py` file in the top level directory of the associated repo.

My application structure, however, is like this:

wsgi
- application (which solely contains `from mybottleapp import application`)
- mybottleapp.py

When I look at the `logs` for one of the `pods`, it shows this error:

```
WARNING: file 'app.py' not found.
ERROR: don't know how to run your application.
Please set either APP_MODULE or APP_FILE environment variables, or create a file 'app.py' to launch your application.
```

Can I set that instead of looking for `app.py` in the top level directory, it instead looks for `/wsgi/application`?

These are the relevant areas from the documentation:

https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/environment_variables.html#set-environment-variables

https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/environment_variables.html#list-environment-variables

But when I try the following to view available variables:

```
oc env pod/username-1-gx3h8 --list
```

I get:

```
# pods username-1-gx3h8, container username
```

I also tried:

```
oc env pod/username-1-gx3h8 APP_FILE=/wsgi/application
```

And got:

```
error: Pod "username-1-gx3h8" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `containers[*].image` or `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have worked, but I don't know if it was the correct way to do it:

```
oc env dc/username APP_FILE=wsgi/application  
deploymentconfig "username" updated
```

`dc` stands for `deploymentconfig` and the name of the `deploymentconfig` was shown at the top of the `Pods` >> `username-1-gx3h8` screen.

Comment: ``APP_FILE`` is correct. See https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/latest/using_images/s2i_images/python.html#configuration

Answer (score 1):

I modified the sample Bottle app for this exact purpose, but it's built in, just not well documented yet.

https://github.com/jfmatth/v3simplebottle.git

you need to change the file .s2i/environment.

It's laid out in the python-s2i docs, but not super clearly.

HTH